# ¿Como replicar la transparencia a ítem seleccionado que implementa GMAIL en Navigation Drawer en Android?

Tags: android, material-design

Estoy utilizando **Navigation drawer** para una aplicación mi objetivo es lograr la transparencia que tiene el nuevo diseño de la aplicación **GMAIL** al seleccionar un **Item**.

[image: Diseño GMAIL]:
Este es mi diseño que tengo actualmente:

[image: Diseño APP]:
Agrego los archivos que he utilizado para generar el diseño:

Estilo agregado en el `NavigationView`

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_color_selected"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/item_color_selected"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/item_background"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**item_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_background_item"
        android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

**custom_background_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent">
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="32dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="32dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

**item_color_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:color="@color/colorWhite"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:color="@color/colorTextPrimary" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas crear un nuevo color en la carpeta `colors.xml` y asignarlo al 
`custom_background_item.xml` ( en lugar de android:color="@color/colorAccent"):

```
 <color name="colorNaranja">#5EF44336</color>
```

Para hacer transparencia es cuestion de mover el 2do slider, de cuadro que aparece al hacer click en el cuadro de color que esta a la izq : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @armen me ha sido útil, he modificado otras cosas y ha quedado correctamente.